# How much extra distance to a CERN event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, curvature, event-horizon

How much extra distance would a scientist have to travel to get to the event horizon of a mini black hole if they ever make one?

Comment: Apart from possible quantum gravity effects that no-one understands, the calculation is exactly the same as for the macroscopic black hole in your previous question.

Comment: From what I have read the curvature at the EH increases as the BH gets smaller. I can't believe the distance increase would be the same for all masses.

Comment: ps. I get it for more than one question in a post and when I divide the questions;-)

Comment: The proper distance, i.e. $\int dr$, will be a function of the mass and so will depend on the mass of the black hole. However there is nothing special about the mini black hole and the same formula will apply to big and mini black holes.

Comment: Does that formula provide a different distance outside the EH for different masses of black holes or is the distance the same even though the curvature is different? some numbers in kilometres would sure help.